# In Django, how can I build a set of criteria from a list?

Tags: sql, django, python-3.x, criteria

I'm using Python 3.7 and Django.  Is there a way I can rewrite the below so taht I just execute one query instead of a bunch?

```
def get_articles_with_words_in_titles(self, long_words):
    result = {}
    for word in long_words:
        qset = Article.objects.filter(title__icontains=word.lower())
        result.extend( qset )
    return result
```

I want to get a unique list of the Article objects that have at least one of the words in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can iterate over it using these libraries like so:

```
from functools import reduce   
from django.db.models import Q
import operator

qset = Article.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, (Q(title__icontains=x) for x in long_words)))
```

Comment: I got an error when I tried your answer as you had it, but when I changed "icontain" to "icontains" everything worked out.

Comment: Fixed! Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with [Q Objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects). They are extremely useful allowing you to chain queries together. Along with `functools`’s `reduce` makes it so you can chain a series of Q objects together.  `reduce` takes two arguments the first is the operator in our case we are using an `or` same as: `|` the second is the series. `reduce` then puts the operator between each element. [More info on reduce and similar functions can be found here](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html).

```
from functools import reduce
import operator
from django.db.models import Q

def get_articles_with_words_in_titles(self, long_words):
result = {}
    q_list = [Q(title__icontains=word) for word in long_words]
    qset = Article.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, q_list)
    result.extend( qset )
    return result
```

This blog post is also really helpful [using Q objects](https://micropyramid.com/blog/querying-with-django-q-objects/)

Comment: This line, "Article.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_(q_list))" is giving me the error, "TypeError: or_ expected 2 arguments, got 1".  I tested it when the "long_words" array contained two strings.

Comment: It should be fixed. I don’t have a way to test the code. I should have put a disclaimer!